# Reading from csv, cell by cell in Node.js

Tags: node.js, csv

I'm beginner to Node.js. Trying to read from a csv file, cell by cell. I used the code below, but this code reads and write all the csv file at once. This shows cloumn[0] of all the rows at once.

```
var csv=require('ya-csv');
var reader= csv.createCsvFileReader('data.csv');
var writer= new csv.CsvWriter(process.stdout);
reader.addListener('data',Function(data) {
writer.writeRecord([data[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps looking into how the listener outputs the data will be useful for your application. In this example the listener is called once for each column. By the way ya-csv doesn't transpose the output.

```
var csv = require('ya-csv');

var reader = csv.createCsvFileReader('data.csv', { 'separator': ',' });
// hello, world
// some, data
reader.setColumnNames([ 'col1', 'col2' ]);
var i = 0 ;
reader.addListener('data', function(data) {
    console.log(i++, data.col1);
    console.log(i++, data.col2);
});
```

> **OUTPUT** 
>    0 hello  
>  1 world 
>   2 some 
>   3 data

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But this code also gives all the data in one column. I want to be able to choose data from a specific row and column. Like row[3]column[2]

Comment: It is not posible with ya-cvs directly. You would have to build this 2d array your self. If posible use another cvs parser!